# Synchronization and concurrency for creating hls resolutions for Live Streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

Is there a single command to transcode mp4 video + aac into HLS at multiple resolutions ?

I have a convert server, and I think to live stream multiple resolutions, I must create all resolutions at the same time and this process must be concurrent.

I raised this issue,because I do this process wtih running these below codes at 4 cmd seperately for creating 4 resolutions of a video examply **at the same time**:
1- 720p

```
ffmpeg -i 123.mp4 -c:a aac -strict experimental -c:v libx264 -s hd720 -aspect 16:9 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -hls_time 2 720p/out.m3u8
```

2- 480p

```
ffmpeg -i 123.mp4 -c:a aac -strict experimental -c:v libx264 -s hd480 -aspect 16:9 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -hls_time 2 480p/out.m3u8
```

3- 360p

```
ffmpeg -i 123.mp4 -c:a aac -strict experimental -c:v libx264 -s nhd -aspect 16:9 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -hls_time 2 360p/out.m3u8
```

4- 200p

```
ffmpeg -i 123.mp4 -c:a aac -strict experimental -c:v libx264 -s cga -aspect 16:9 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -hls_time 2 200p/out.m3u8
```

but doing in this way have some problems.

1- the .TS parts of each resolutions doesn't create with another resolutions part at the same time(this issue makes that in switching resolutions, player cannot seek to the continue of selected resolution,because that part doesn't create yet).

2- You have run some threads for each live streaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer of mine,Note that you must be set **-hls_time** If you want the number part of each resolutions be same.

```
ffmpeg -re -i 123.mp4 
-c:a aac -c:v libx264 -s hd480 -aspect 16:9 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -hls_time 2 480p/out.m3u8  
-c:a aac -c:v libx264 -s nhd -aspect 16:9 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -hls_time 2 360p/out.m3u8 
-c:a aac -c:v libx264 -s cga -aspect 16:9 -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -hls_time 2 200p/out.m3u8
```